# Is there a more polite way to say "Haven't seen you for a while / for ages / for yonks."

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose a professor in our department went to a conference for several weeks, is there a more polite way to say something like

> Hi professor, haven't seen you for a while / for ages / for yonks.

Comment: Why do you think "Hi professor, haven't seen you for a while" wouldn't be polite enough?

Comment: "For yonks"? I've never heard this before. Is it regional to some area?

Comment: @RobK I thought it is used between close friends. But if it is already polite enough, please ignore my question...

Comment: Because of the nature of the word, "yonks" is listed at almost the end of the dictionary, @Cat, and thus, curious cats like me (and probably the OP) stumble upon it and think "Oh, another new fancy word I can use instead of *age*". That it's not common at all in some dialects with such a common meaning is irrelevant.

Comment: "I haven't seen you for awhile" is plenty polite enough. I would avoid the others since they're slang.

Comment: @RobK - One could say that 'for ages' is hyperbole. "...for a long time" would be a good fit, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yonks

would be very informal.

> haven't seen you for a while
>   haven't seen you for a long time

would be appropriate when speaking with your professor, as would

> it's been a while